# Angular, trigger a function from a controller in a directives controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I know you can get a function in a directive to fire a function in a controller (see : [AngularJS - pass function to directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378520/angularjs-pass-function-to-directive) ), however, right now I am trying to acheive something slightly different.

I'm trying to have a function in a controller fire a function inside a controller in the directive (so handled within the directive). So I click the button from the controller outside the directive, and it fires a function inside the directive.

Here is what I have tried

The directive:

```
return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            controller: EditorCtrl.componentName,
            scope: {
                content: '=',
                requestNow: '@'
            },
            templateUrl: 'editor.html'
        };
```

The directive in use :

```
  <div cengage-file-editor content="XmlContent" request-now="changeXml()"></div>
```

the outer controllers function:

```
  $scope.changeXml = function(){
     //fire function inside directive controller?
       };
```

The function inside the directive controller:

```
 $scope.changeXml = function(){
            console.log("hit");
           }
```

So basically, I want the user to have fired the changeXml function (outside of the directive) and have it send into the directive and connect and fire a function inside there. Not sure how to accomplish this, would love some help. Thanks!

Comment: Directives are supposed to be somewhat self-contained so I don't think this is a good use-case for directives.  Instead you could create a service that performs the functionality you need and inject this service into both controllers

Answer (score -1):

You will have to watch for something that exists on the controller to trigger the function that is in the directive's controller.

html code:
 `<div cengage-file-editor content="XmlContent" changeXmlTrigger="somethingChanged"></div>`

The outer controller's function:

```
$scope.changeXml = function(){
  $scope.somethingChanged = true;
};
```

In the directive's controller:

```
$scope.$watch('somethingChanged', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if(newVal && newVal !== oldVal) {
    $scope.changeXml();
  }
});

$scope.changeXml = function(){
  console.log("hit");
}
```

Comment: Not trying to pass up , trying to pass from the parent controller down into the directives controller. So there is a function outside the directive that when I press, I would like it to fire something inside the directive.

Comment: if that's the case you have to $watch over an object inside the directive that gets changed from within the function in the controller, editing my answer now.

Comment: Directive has isolated scope, how can it watch 'somethingChanged'

Comment: If you look at the definition of the person who asked the question he/she is binding something called `content` to the *scope* of the directive `content: '='` if he binds that "content" locally defined to something that is defined in the Controller's scope then he can WATCH it. Directives _can_ have isolated scopes but that's not the case in this question.