# AngularJs: Passing Function Arguments Across Multiple Isolated Scopes with Angular Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 nested, isolate scope, directives ([see CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPNowN?editors=101)) and I am able to pass a function (that takes an argument) from the outermost directive to the innermost directive (passing the function from outer directive to intermediate directive to inner directive).

What I'm failing to understand is what needs to be done to pass the argument from the inner directive back through intermediate directive back to the outer directive.

Again, see [the CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPNowN?editors=101).

Note:  Given only 2 isolate scope directives I can get this to work with something similar to the following...

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myDir1', function() {
    return {
      template: '<div><my-dir-2 add-name="addName(name)"></my-dir-2></div>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.addName = function(name) {
          alert(name); // alerts 'Henry'
        };
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('myDir2', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        addName: '&'
      },
      template: "<span ng-click='addName({name: testName})'>Click to Add {{testName}}!</span>",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.testName = 'Henry';
      }
    }
  });
```

The above code gives me an Alert box with 'Henry' (just like I'd expect).

It's when I add an third, intermediate, isolate scope directive that I run into problems...

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myDir1', function() {
    return {
      template: '<div><my-dir-2 add-name="addName(name)"></my-dir-2></div>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.addName = function(name) {
          alert(name); // alerts 'Henry'
        };
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('myDir2', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        addName: '&'
      },
      template: '<div><my-dir-3 add-name="addName({name: testName})"></my-dir-3></div>',
    }
  })
  .directive('myDir3', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        addName: '&'
      },
      template: "<span ng-click='addName({name: testName})'>Click to Add {{testName}}!</span>",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.testName = 'Henry';
      }
    }
  });
```

This code gives me an alert box with `undefined`...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A common misconception is that "& is for passing functions".  This isn't technically correct.

What `&` does is create a *function* on the directive scope that, when called, returns the result of the expression evaluated against the parent scope.

This function takes an object as an argument that will override local variables in the expression with those from the directive scope (the `{name: testName}`) object in this case.

If you were to look under the hood, the `$scope.addName` method in `myDir2` would look like this (simplified):

```
$scope.addName = function(locals) {
    return $parse(attr.addName)($scope.$parent, locals);
}
```

Your second directive works because the expression it is binding to is

```
addName(name)
```

This expression has a local variable `name`, that is overridden with the value of testName from the directive when executed with

```
addName({name: testName}) //in the directive.
```

Remember - the `addName` function in `myDir2` IS NOT the same as the `addName` function in `myDir1`.  It is a new function that evaluates the expression

```
addName(name)
```

against the parent scope and returns the result.

When you apply this logic to `myDir3`, the expression that is evaluated is:

```
addName({name: testName})
```

Note that the only local variable in this expression is "testName".  So when you call in `myDir3` with

```
addName({name: testName})
```

there is no local variable `name` to override, and `testName` is left undefined.

Phew!  No wonder this confuses JUST ABOUT EVERYBODY!

How to fix in your example:

You want the expressions to evaluate to the actual function in `myDir1`.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('myDir1', function() {
    return {
      template: '<div><my-dir-2 add-name="addName"></my-dir-2></div>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.addName = function(name) {
          alert(name); // alerts 'Henry'
        };
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('myDir2', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        addName: '&'
      },
      // addName() returns the actual function addName from myDir1
      template: '<div><my-dir-3 add-name="addName()"></my-dir-3></div>',
    }
  })
  .directive('myDir3', function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        addName: '&'
      },
      //calls addName() on myDir2, which returns addName from myDir1, then invokes it passing testName as an argument
      template: "<span ng-click='addName()(testName)'>Click to Add {{testName}}!</span>",
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.testName = 'Henry';
      }
    }
  });
```

[Here is the working Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNaypw)

Final note - the reason why `'&'` is more appropriate than `'='` here is that `'='` is going to actually set up a `$watch` and two-way bind the variables between the directives.  This means that `myDir2` could actually change the function `appName` in `myDir1`, which is not required and undesirable.  It also requires setting up two `$watch`s, which I try to avoid for performance reasons in Angular.

Comment: awesome answer, really learning something here! what I don't understand: on top level, you'd usually pass the function inside the template via `add-name="addName(name)"`, like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18378602/3779853 . Why  does the highest-level-"pass" have to be `add-name="addName"` without the parameter, in `myDir1`s template?

Comment: @Blauhirn - if you try to pass it in as `add-name="addName(name)"`, the `addName` function would execute immediately, and the result of the function would be passed in, not the reference to the function.

Comment: any idea how we write karma unit testing for addName()(testName) this.?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to pass a function in an isolated scope. While '&' will make sure that what you are passing is in-fact a function, you can also pass a function as a bound variable with '=', and invoke it only when you need. This method has drawbacks, but it will leave the control of the invocation to the component that is in-charge of that invocation.

[Your codepen working](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpYJNJ?editors=101)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
 .directive('myDir1', function() {
    return {
      template: '<div><my-dir-2 add-name="addName"></my-dir-2></div>',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.addName = function(name) {
        alert(name);
      };
    }
  }
})
.directive('myDir2', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      addName: '='
    },
    template: '<div><my-dir-3 add-name="addName"></my-dir-3></div>'
  }
})
.directive('myDir3', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      addName: '='
    },
    template: "<span ng-click='addName(testName)'>Click to Add {{testName}}!</span>",      
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.testName = "Henry"
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code with three nested directives is that `testName` does not exist in isolated scope of `myDir2`. You can set that from `myDir3`, but for that you will have to create an object in scope of `myDir2` and set its property to testName and then use that property in `myDir2`

The working example is here 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wveqwx

Answer (score 0):

'myDir2' when you have 3 directives is referencing 'testName', but it doesn't exist in that scope. It was mapped to 'name' in the 'myDir3'. Because of this, changing the template in myDir2 as follows, should fix it:

```
template: '<div><my-dir-3 add-name="addName({name: name})"></my-dir-3></div>'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access an elements scope using `isolateScope()`

In the `myDir1` directive replace the `controller` to this instead

```
  link: function($scope, elem) {
    $scope.addName = function(name) {
      var e = elem.find('my-dir-3');
      var s = e.isolateScope();
      alert(s.testName);
    };
```

Another way is to potentially use `$$nextSibling` to get the next scope after current parent (haven't really used this so may want to read up on it)

This is probably not the 'angular way' to do things. I think removing the isolated scope from the child directives and having them reference the parent directive model would be more ideal.