# set scope variable from outside controller in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to set a $scope variable of a controller from outside the controller?

For example, if I have a controller:

```
app.controller('citySelectCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope){

}]);
```

And a function in the global scope which has an event handler. Now I want to set a `$scope` variable when that event happens. Is it possible? My global function:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {
            componentRestrictions: {'country': 'in'},
            types: ['(cities)']
        });
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 22.5937, lng: 78.9629},
        zoom: 5,
        minZoom: 5
    });
}

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
      return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
      map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
----------------------------------------------------------
    //SET $scope.city = place here
----------------------------------------------------------
    infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
```

Comment: Pass this controller scope as parameter to that function

Comment: you can use $rootscope variable place of $scope to set  global value

Comment: like @ramsingh mentioned `$rootScope` is a  global variable which can be used across all controllers in your module unlike `$scope` which is specific to current controller.

Comment: And $rootscope is the property of...? app?

Comment: @dreamweiver How do I access $rootScope outside of the angular app scope?

Comment: `$rootScope` is the scope variable for your angular module, which means you cant access it outside your angular app, but you can access it anywhere in your module app , in controller, services,etc.,

Comment: Have you tried [Angular Google Map directives](https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/google-map)
I think this might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `$injector` for accessing Angular Services Outside Scope.
For your example.

```
// If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
if (place.geometry.viewport) {
  map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
} else {
  map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
  map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
}
----------------------------------------------------------
    var elem = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]'));
    var injector = elem.injector();
     var $rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');   
     $rootScope.$apply(function(){
       $rootScope.city = place //or city;
     });
----------------------------------------------------------
infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

and in your controller you could use.

```
app.controller('citySelectCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope',
    function ($scope,$rootScope) {         
         $rootScope.city = {};

    }
]);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/manishiitg/pen/bNMVxZ)**</kbd>

For more details view [this](http://excellencenodejsblog.com/angularjs-access-scope-from-outside-function/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

use can use $rootScope like this.

```
app.controller('citySelectCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){
    //$rootScope.city = place here;
}]);
```

and use can access the variable in global function

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    //$rootScope.city = place here;
}
```

Comment: The global function is being called on a script load. I can't call it unless the script has loaded.

Comment: use can use $rootScope

Comment: $rootScope is not a declared variable. It isn't available like you are using it here.

Comment: yes I know it's not declared variable. it can be set at state level and use in controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using $broadcast from the $rootscope to notify your controller that the event has occurred.

```
//rootscope
$rootscope.$broadcast("myevent",eventObjectToBePassed);

//your controller
$scope.$on("myevent",function(eventObject){

//do something

});
```

A cleaner way would be to inject rootscope in a service and create a sendEvent function to actually do $rootscope.$broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a global scope variable directly when working with angular apps. The way it is recommended is to wrap this functionality in a directive and use the directive in your templates. This way you will hvae access to the `$scope`to update the value. E.g.:

```
angular.directive('mapAutoComplete', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
      // Add your map and autocomplete here

      // Now you can use the `scope` to update the $scope of the parent controller
    }
  }
});
```

In your html, use the directive like this:

```
<map-auto-complete></map-auto-complete>
```

This will make the scope from the controller of the containing view available as `scope` within the directive

Refer these for best practices on using `directives` over direct dom manipulation and reusable functionality
http://ng-learn.org/2014/01/Dom-Manipulations/ 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/3878940

Comment: I need to give the Google maps API a callback to call when the script loads. How should I give it a non global function?

Comment: You can use the `scope` property in the directive definition to pass values into the directive. Refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18378602/3878940 answer on SO

Comment: This is where the call back goes: `script(src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=**initAutocomplete**&libraries=places", async, defer)` What should I replace it with?

Answer (score 0):

I can think about two ways to do this

1. Use the `$rootScope` which is the easy way to do it. But I personally don't like it to much if it isn't really a global variable.
2. Write a Eventhandler and listen in the controller

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var requiredElemScope = angular.element(ELEMENT_SELECTOR).scope();` to get the scope of the element. Then you can assign value to the scope variable as `requiredElemScope.city = someValue;`

Here `ELEMENT_SELECTOR` is the dom selector to which the controller is attached.