# Angular 1.5 Component Bindings: Check if Callback is Present

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components, angularjs-bindings

I've got a simple `contactList` component, which has 2 bindings: `contacts` and `onRemove`.

- `contacts` is just an array of contacts to display
- `onRemove` is a callback function

```js
app
  .component('contactList', {
    template: 
      `<div ng-repeat="c in $ctrl.contacts">
         {{c.name}}
         <div ng-click="$ctrl.onRemove({contact: c})">Remove</div>
       </div>`,
    bindings: {
      contacts: '<',
      onRemove: '&'
    },
    controller: function() {}
  })
```

I use this component multiple times within my app. And the `onRemove` callback can behave differently, depending on *where* the `contactList` component is getting used. Example:

- `contactMainView` (= component) displays a search bar and the resulting list of contacts using the `contactList` component. `onRemove` will delete the contact from the database.
- `groupMembersView` displays all contacts belonging to the given group using the `contactList` component. **Here it shouldn't be possible to remove a contact, though `onRemove` will not be set.**

---

### Ideas:

First I thought, that I could use an `ng-if="$ctrl.onRemove"` but that doesn't work, because `onRemove` is never `undefined` within `contactList` component. `console.log(this.onRemove)` always prints: `function(locals) { return parentGet(scope, locals); }`

Of course I could use another `showRemove: '@'` binding, but that doesn't look *DRY* to me.

---

Do you have any idea or some better solution to get things done?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest way would to check if the attribute is defined. In your controller inject `$attrs` and then you can do:

```
if( $attrs.onRemove ) { //Do something }
```

Using the `&` binding angular will wrap the function in order to keep references to the original `$scope` of the passed method, even if is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the function onRemove on component allow to get if a function was passed in parameter. So you can use ng-if="$ctrl.onRemove()"

```
component('contactList', {
template: 
  `<div ng-repeat="c in $ctrl.contacts">
     {{c.name}}
     <div ng-click="$ctrl.onRemove()({contact: c})" ng-if="$ctrl.onRemove()">Remove</div>
   </div>`,
bindings: {
  contacts: '<',
  onRemove: '&'
},
controller: function() {
  console.log(this.onRemove);
  console.log(this.onRemove());
}
})
```

Comment: `console.log(this.onRemove());` throws an exception somewhere in the code when I pass some function to `on-remove="..."`, But it prints `undefined` when it's no defined.

Comment: how to define a callback function binding please?

Comment: Please see this post, it answerd to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378520/angularjs-pass-function-to-directive

Answer (score 0):

another option is to define the callback as optional by adding a question mark in the binding definition:
`onRemove: '&?'`

text from the documentation: [All 4 kinds of bindings (@, =, <, and &) can be made optional by adding ? to the expression. The marker must come after the mode and before the attribute name. See the Invalid Isolate Scope Definition error for definition examples.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)