# How to check if output binding is given?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

How to check if output binding is given?

Examplecode:

```
angular.module('tester', []);
angular.module('tester').component('test', {
    template: '<h3></h3>',
    bindings: {
      callback : '&'
    },
    controller: function() {
       // How to check if callback binding is given?
       // typeof this.callback === 'function' returns true
       // angular.isFunction(this.callback) also returns true 
    }
});
```

Comment: the following post might answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38914917/2106610

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if binding is given just do:

```
   if(this.callback)
      return true
    else 
      return false
```

The value of the this.callback will be available in the component if the binding is there otherwise it wont be.

Comment: Not working because the binding is always a function.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your binding to being optional, then it will be undefined if not supplied and you can check if it was given using the methods you've already mentioned.

```
bindings: {
  callback : '&?'
},
```