# Call a controller's function from component

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I'm trying to call a controller's function from a component. Here are my files:

controller.js:

```
$scope.dataTableDevices = {
    title: 'title',
    color: {'background' : 'rgb(31, 119, 180)'},
    items: [0, 1, 2]
};
$scope.hacerClick = function(){
    alert("it works");
}
```

view.html:

```
<device-categories data="dataTableDevices"></device-categories>
```

deviceCategories.js:

```
function deviceCategoriesController() {
}

widgetsFactory.component('deviceCategories', {
    templateUrl: 'app/common/js/components/deviceCategories/deviceCategories.html',
    controller: deviceCategoriesController,
    bindings: {
        data: '='
    }
});
```

deviceCategories.html:

```
<md-button ng-click="howToCallhacerClick()">
    Click
</md-button>
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378520/angularjs-pass-function-to-directive

Comment: I have not been able to solve the problem. Components behave a little bit different than directives, right?

Answer (score 2):

Components are like directives having an isolated scope.

If you wish to call a function which is in parent scope/ controllers scope then do the following

Consider the following method in your controller:

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.validateInputByUser = function (obj) {
        if (obj['note'].length > 255) {
            return false;
            }
            return true;
        };
});
```

1. Create a component

   ```
   angular.module('MyApp')
   .component('notes', { 
                           templateUrl: "/Templates/Notes.html", 
                           controllerAs: 'model', 
                           controller: NotesController, 
                           bindings: { 
                               note: '=' 
   }});
   ```
2. Create a controller with name 'NotesController' with $scope injection, as component is the child of controller, controllers 'scope' is accessible as $parent in the component.

   ```
   function NotesController ($scope) {
       // binding parent method to scope of current component
       $scope.validateInputByUser = $scope.$parent.validateInputByUser;
   };
   ```
3. Now, you can implement and access the controllers method by the following:

   Html on notes template (/Templates/Notes.html) looks like

   ```
   <textarea type="text" ng-model="model.note" ng-blur="validateInputByUser(model)"/>
   ```

   Html on the component implementation page looks like

   ```
   <notes note="obj.notes"/>
   ```

> Now, every time user enters text and leaves the text area the controller's function 'validateInputByUser' will be called.

Hope this helps! Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the function to your component from your controller using the '&' binding which is used for callbacks to component events. So You'll need to do something like this:

**component**

```
.component('deviceCategories',{
    template: `<div>
                   <md-button ng-click="$ctrl.hacerClickFn()">Click Me!
                   </md-button>
               </div>,
    bindings: {
        data:'=', //assuming you need two way binding
        hacerFunc:'&'
     },
     controller: [function(){
         var ctrl = this;

          ctrl.hacerClickFn = function() {
              ctrl.hacerFunc();
          }
     }]
 });
```

**View**

```
<device-categories data="data" hacer-func="hacerClick()"</device-categories>
```

[AngularJS Component Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

[Great explanation of differences between components and directives](https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/)