# Get value from directive in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

> I know these kind of questions have been asked many time before but none of them working for me. I'm new to directive working, may be its lack of learning that I'm unable to resolve my issue.

I've a variable in directive that I need in controller but there's no way to pass that value. Here is my directive code

```
return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        image: '=ngModel',
        allowedTypes: '@accept',
        dimensionRestrictions: '&dimensions',
      },
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        element.bind('change', function(event) {
          var file = (event.srcElement || event.target).files[0];
          ngModel.$setViewValue(file, 'change');
        });
      };
     }
```

I need `file` variable in controller but I don't know how to do this...
I've tried [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8masomq/) but its not working in my case.

Any Kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: The best way to share variables/values between directives or controllers is to use a service. Create an angular service and set the value in it. Inject this service to directive and contorller and you have access to the variable in both

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: How are you using this directive? It looks like you are creating a directive for an element  that has both the `ng-model` directive and your custom directive. In that case the isolate scope of the custom directive will fight the  scope of the `ng-model` directive. The `ng-model` controller expects sibling directives have no scope.

Comment: This link has an example with explanation https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/services

Answer (score 0):

You can send a function from the controller to the directive where you can pass your `file` variable

See this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378520/angularjs-pass-function-to-directive) , It'll work on your case

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
```