# calling angularjs controller based method from custom directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-steps

I am using jquery steps in my angularjs app. I have used a custom directive to init the jquery plugin. Now I need to validate all input once the finish button is clicked on the final steps of the form. In order to do that I know there is a option which needs to be set called onFinished. Now how do I call my controller method in this section?

```
app.directive('step', [function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        stepChanging: '='
      },
      compile: function(element, attr) {
          element.steps({
          labels: {finish: "SUBMIT"},  
          headerTag: "h3",
          bodyTag: "section",
          transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
          stepsOrientation: "vertical",
          onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
             console.log("submit button has been clicked");

             $scope.validator(); //problem here 

          }
        });
        return {
          //pre-link
          pre:function() {},
          //post-link
          post: function(scope, element) {
            //element.on('stepChanging', scope.stepChanging);
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }])
```

Comment: Are you talking about the page controller, or the controller for this directive?

Comment: @rrd  page controller. the controller which has the form. i have a method there called validator

Answer (score 0):

you directive is isolated scope , it cannot access controller scope , if u want to pass functions you can use `&` in scope object of your directive like below

```
scope:{

validator:'&'

}
```

and in your directive pass this function as below

```
<step validator='validator'/>
```

Comment: DO you mean in my controller i can pass this function like ?
<step validator='validator'/>

Comment: Yes , please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378520/angularjs-pass-function-to-directive

Answer (score 0):

To pass events from a directive with isolate scope to parent controller, use expression `&` binding.

During the directive compile phase, there is no scope for a function use.
Move the function to the postLink:

```
app.directive('step', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        //stepChanging: '=',
        stepChanging: '<',
        //USE expression binding
        validator: '&'
      },
      //compile: function(element, attr) {
      link: function postLink(scope,element,attrs) {
          element.steps({
              labels: {finish: "SUBMIT"},  
              headerTag: "h3",
              bodyTag: "section",
              transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
              stepsOrientation: "vertical",
              onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
                 console.log("submit button has been clicked");

                 //$scope.validator(); //problem here 
                 scope.validator();
              }
          );
        } 
        /*
        return {
          //pre-link
          pre:function() {},
          //post-link
          post: function(scope, element) {
            //element.on('stepChanging', scope.stepChanging);
          }
        }*/
      }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<step step-changing="vm.changing" validator="validator()">
</step>
```

Moving forward, avoid using two-way `=` binding. Instead use one-way `<` binding. It is more efficient and provides a better path for migrating to Angular 2+.

Also avoid closing element directives with `/>` it causes problems with some browsers. Instead use a closing tag `</step>`.