# Angular 1.5 ng-change on select element in component triggering previous response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components, angularjs-ng-change

I'm just starting to play with components in Angular 1.5.x and have created one for a select box on a form - I pass in the field, list and label to the component and it creates the form 'part' consisting of the label and select box with the correct options - so far, so good.

Now I want to implement an ng-change on the select so I am passing in the function I want to use for this. The problem I have is that the function is triggering with the old value for the select not the new value. I can see that the function is triggering prior to the actual change. If I put the change function within the component change event it registers correctly, but not using a passed in function.

I have created a cut-down fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/7gd3m2k0/

```
<div ng-app="demoApp">
  <div ng-controller="RoleController as ctrl">
    <nac-select       
      field="ctrl.MemberRole.record.member" 
      list="ctrl.Lists.Member" 
      label="Member" 
      on-change="ctrl.MemberRole.changeMember();"></nac-select>
    <div ng-bind="ctrl.MemberRole.record.member.name"></div>
  </div>
</div>

angular.module('demoApp', [])
.component('nacSelect', nacSelect)
.controller('RoleController', roleController)

var nacSelect = {
bindings: {
            field: '=',
            list: '<',
            label: '@label',
            onChange: '&'
        },
        controller: function () {
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.change = function () {                    
                alert(ctrl.field.name); //gives new selection
                ctrl.onChange(); //gives previous selection
            }
        },
    template: `

    <label>{{$ctrl.label}}</label>
    <select ng-model="$ctrl.field" ng-options="r as r.name for r in $ctrl.list" ng-change="$ctrl.change();">
      <option value="">(Please Select)</option>
    </select>
`
};

var roleController = function(){
var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.Lists = {
Member: [
  {id: 1, name: 'Fred Smith'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Jenny Jones'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Jane Doe'}
]
  };

ctrl.MemberRole = {
record: {
    member: null
},
    changeMember: function(){
    alert(ctrl.MemberRole.record.member.name);    
    }  
  };
};
```

I guess I am missing something simple, but I can't figure it out. Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in variable that you want to alert in the first controller, check this:

https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/7gd3m2k0/1/

so your function would look like this:

```
changeMember: function(name){
        alert(name);
    }
```

when you're using nac-select

```
 <nac-select field="ctrl.MemberRole.record.member" list="ctrl.Lists.Member" label="Member" on-change="ctrl.MemberRole.changeMember(name);"></nac-select>
```

and in the end in the nac-select:

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.field" ng-options="r as r.name for r in $ctrl.list | orderBy: 'name'" ng-required="$ctrl.req" ng-if="!$ctrl.list.processing" ng-change="$ctrl.onChange($ctrl.field)">
```

or if you want to pass in object:

```
<nac-select field="ctrl.MemberRole.record.member" list="ctrl.Lists.Member" label="Member" on-change="ctrl.MemberRole.changeMember({id, name});"></nac-select>
```

then your changeMember can look like this:

```
changeMember: function(obj){
        alert(`${obj.name} ${obj.id}`);
    }
```

New fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/pegla/7gd3m2k0/2/

Comment: thank you, but what if I want to pass the whole object? there are two objects - a member and a role. the main controller's function is basically: if(member is object and role is object) then do some checks - that's why I was trying to use the model's value in that function.

Comment: it's same to pass object, check updated answer, also I have to say that even though this will work I would rethink your approach, if you started with component based architecture, you shouldn't be using 2 way bindings and relaying on parent components as whole purpose is to isolate components to make them small and reusable. I would recommend to read this, really best tutorial about component based architecture online: https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide

Comment: thank you very much - i just figured out the sending object thing as a result of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378520/angularjs-pass-function-to-directive. I will read your suggestion because i thought i was making the component small and reusable by passing in the function I wanted when the select changes :).

Comment: No problem, you can accept the answer if it was helpful.