# AngularJS directive with binded function patrameter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, syntax-error

I have an AngularJS directive with function parameter, and it works perfectly when I call the directive simply it works, and I want to generalize it.
What I got so far:

```
.directive('panelBox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            values: '=',
            calculatefn: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: '/ProfitCalculator/PanelBox',
        controller: function ($scope) {


            $scope.calculate=function() {
                $scope.calculatefn();
            }
        }
    }
})
```

in the main scope:

```
$scope.smartBookValues= {
name:'Smart Book',
text:'Smart book header',
controls:[]
};
```

and the html:

```
<panel-box values="smartBookValues" calculateFn="smartBookCalculateFn()"></panel-box>
```

now I'm trying to bind the values and calculateFn, so I started with calculateFn and did:

```
$scope.smartBookValues= {
name:'Smart Book',
text:'Smart book header',
controls:[],
calculateFn:'smartBookCalculateFn()'
};
```

and the html:

```
<panel-box values="smartBookValues" calculateFn="{{smartBookValues.calculateFn}}"></panel-box>
```

but i get: [$parse:syntax]

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{smartBookValues.calculateFn}}] starting at [{smartBookValues.calculateFn}}].

Comment: You're passing the function as a String, have you tried passing an actual function?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Declare ```calculateFn: function() { console.log('something') }```, remove the braces in the HTML and pass the attribute with a hyphen like this: ```calculate-fn="smartBookCalculateFn()"```. Also you declared the scope in the directive as ```calculatefn``` with a lower case ```f```, be careful with that.

Comment: not working at all now,doesn't get to the function. Also its still not binding to a dynamic function name stored in my scope...

Answer (score 0):

First, you declare as:

```
calculatefn: '&'   <-- small 'f'
```

so syntax in html is like:

```
<panel-box values="smartBookValues" calculatefn="smartBookValues.calculateFn"></panel-box>  <-- no need for {{}}, as you passing as reference to scope, not as text
```

search Google for "how to pass function in to angular directive"

Comment: works either way it seems. and as for your last sentence, that was the first thing i searched before coming here..

Comment: this has nice example actually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378520/angularjs-pass-function-to-directive