# AngularJs - communication between controller and directive

Tags: angularjs, function, controller, call, directive

For example;

GetSwatchCartListFunc: How do I access this method directly from the directive

**homeController.js**

```
(function (App) {
    var Home = function Home($scope, MemberService) {


        $scope.GetSwatchCartListFunc = function (patternDetailLineId) {
            MemberService.GetSwatchCartList(patternDetailLineId).then(function (res) {
                console.log(res.data);
                if (res.data.status === ServiceResulState.Success) {
                    $scope.SwatchCartListData = res.data.resultList;
                    $('#swathcartList').modal('show');
                } else if (res.data.status === ServiceResulState.Fail) {
                    toastr.warning(res.data.message);
                    $('#userLoginModal').modal('show');
                }
            });
        };


    };

    Home.$inject = ["$scope", "MemberService"];

    App.controller("HomeController", Home);
})(App);
```

**directive.js**

```
(function (App) {
App.directive("ngPatternPre", ['toastr', function (toastr) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/views/Directives/NgPattern.html'    
        }
    };
}]);})(App);
```

**NgPattern.html**

```
<a ng-click="SwatchCartList(pId)" title="Add"><i class="ti-Line-Gallery"></i></a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS - pass function to directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378520/angularjs-pass-function-to-directive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following change is required to solve the problem in **directive.js**

**directive.js**

```
(function (App) {
App.directive("ngPatternPre", ['toastr', function (toastr) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/views/Directives/NgPattern.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                

            scope.SwatchCartList = function (pId) {
                scope.GetSwatchCartListFunc(pId);                   
            };

        }
    };
}]);})(App);
```